# Youtube DataAPI - Endscreen and cards list and set API

Tags: youtube-data-api

I have a requirement,

1. To see for which videos end-screen and cards are set.
2. Videos set in cards and end-screen.
3. Update API to update end-screen and cards.

But I do not see any such API is available.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible, nor will it ever be as far as i can tell.

Not being able to add annotations is an intended behaviour. See this link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35166657 - Status: Won't Fix (Intended behavior)